# Error in shapiro.test(group1[, i]) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE

Tags: r

I'm working with this code and always have the same error:

````
pvalShapirogroup2=rep(0,variables)
group1=data[class==1,]
group2=data[class==2,]
for (i in 1:variables)
    {shapiro1=shapiro.test(group1[,i])
    shapiro2=shapiro.test(group2[,i])
    pvalShapirogroup1[i]=shapiro1$p.value
    pvalShapirogroup2[i]=shapiro2$p.value}```
Error in shapiro.test(group1[, i]) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
````

Comment: You are looping on variables: are they all numeric? You can check with `str(data)`. Also, while it's not really a bug, it does not help reading to name variables like existing R objects or functions, namely `class` and `data`.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help without posting a reproducible example. However, it seems like the variable on which the shapiro.test() should run is not numeric, you may want to transform it with `as.numeric()` prior to run the code.